# PHP NumberFormatter remove currency code prefix

Tags: php, currency, numberformatter

I want to use same currency code across all different locale. But i want to remove short currency code prefix from amount and only use currency symbol with amount.

for example:
suppose default currency code is USD and locale is any one like en_US or en_CA.

the current output is in en_CA case:
CA$100.00

But actually output is needed:
$100.00

Solution needed in PHP language.

Tried code is

```
$locale = 'en_US';
$currencyCode = 'CAD'; // Canadian Dollar
$amount = 1234.56;

$formatter = new NumberFormatter($locale, NumberFormatter::CURRENCY);

$formatted = $formatter->formatCurrency($amount, $currencyCode);
echo $formatted.PHP_EOL;  // Output: $1,234.56
```

Comment: In en_CA it outputs $1,234.56. https://onlinephp.io?s=XU9NC4IwGL4H_Yf3IGhgin0dtA9kGh1CRejQSdZcGOgmYyP69800wm4vz_e7PbRVO50YNSe4prADk7IChWagMaKEoIy8EC8_DAojMwDXBYQZLh-YQcTrGgstxQ1XTGqRt1iunPVG2zV656LBUlKhCUafkKjmRsXxi1pDq_1P-D665HmcoOtsHFTqoF_qfN-faNhpDTNsGE3vMiip-M9ZOtkpK-L0HED3Tqpkq6QPhmf367vONw%2C%2C&v=8.1.19 In en_US, of course CA$ will be displayed because $ means US dollars.

Comment: It is unclear what you want. Do you want the output to be locale aware or not? Please [edit] your question to include several situations of your input data and the result you want. Also explain how/where you set your locale in your application and why.

Comment: I don't think there is a way to use `formatCurrency` _without_ a currency. If you can't use the normal `format` method with one of the formats available - then you will have to _remove_ the currency symbol from your result here yourself. If you know the currency code upfront, then you could also know what you need to remove; otherwise, removing everything until the first digit should probably do. (Unless you also work with currencies, where the currency symbol gets placed _after_ the value ...?)